How does torque gets divided in a Split Torque Transmission?
I'm interested in understanding torque flows in transmissions to calculate efficiency losses.
I came across an example of a helicopter transmission where one gear meshes with two other gears and later, they connect through another gear (see image).

I also came across a NASA paper where they study this specific transmission. In their results they show that the ideal split should be 50/50 (see fig. 8 in the attached link).
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19930003548/downloads/19930003548.pdf
My question is what would happen if those paths had different ratios? How is torque supposed to split? What would the total output torque be? The bigger one of those or a combination of the two?
Maybe as an extra question, but is the same thing happening in an automatic transmission such as the one in the next image? Specifically in the 2 gears attached to the blue shaft.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

How can there be different ratios if the intermediate gears both mesh with the same output gear?

Frankly, I'm not even sure if it's possible, but maybe offsetting the angle between the three shafts so that one of them is slightly higher and a gear with more teeth can fit.

the design in the first picture may be some form of failsafe configuration

jsotola - no i think it is just lighter/smaller than a single gear intermediate. So you could do it with sya  a 10:20 10:100 and a 10:40 20:100 but i can see no advantage in doing so
